# C# Linq to Entities adding a second condition using && kills query

Tags: c#, sql, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a pretty simple query in C# 6 using EF 6 where I need to check for records that fall between two dates.  If I just use a single check for >= it executes in seconds, as soon as I add the second test it take almost a full minute.
To work around it I am having to run a second query against the first, but I don't like that.

Here is the current working solution:

```
var stopEvents = (from s in dbContext.stop_event
                           join d in dbContext.stop_details on s.stop_id equals d.id
                           where (d.ship_date >= startDate)
                           select new
                                        {
                                            deliveryID = s.id,
                                            stopID = d.id,
                                            d.ship_date,
                                            d.verified_ship_date,
                                            d.cust_ref_1_BOL,
                                            d.cust_ref_2_OrderNum,
                                            d.cust_ref_3_stopID,
                                            d.con_name,
                                            d.con_address1,
                                            d.con_address2,
                                            d.con_city,
                                            con_zip = d.con_zip.Substring(0, 5),
                                            d.customer.customer_name,
                                            d.con_state,
                                            d.lading_qty_total,
                                            d.lading_wgt_total,
                                            d.lading_qty_haz,
                                            d.lading_wgt_haz,
                                            delivery_record_created = s.record_created,
                                            delivery_record_updated = s.record_updated,
                                            stop_record_created = d.record_created,
                                            d.stop_canceled,
                                            d.stop_changed,
                                            d.status,
                                            d.items_del_ytd,
                                            d.wgt_del_ytd,
                                            d.note_from_cust,
                                            noteTest = d.note_from_cust,
                                            d.con_contact_email,
                                            d.con_contact_name,
                                            d.con_contact_phone,
                                            d.del_req_date,
                                            d.customer_id,
                                            d.cust_unique_id,
                                            s.driver_id,
                                            s.event_datetime,
                                            s.received_by,
                                            s.stop_note,
                                            s.edi_shipment_status_codes.Description,
                                            s.exception_status_code,
                                            s.needs_EDI_gen_flag,
                                            s.review_level,
                                            d.eCourier_export_flag,
                                            s.ontime_performance,
                                            s.batch_number
                                        }).ToArray();

        stopEvents = (from s in stopEvents where s.ship_date <= endDate select s).ToArray();
```

and if I just make this change it "breaks" it:

```
   var stopEvents = (from s in dbContext.stop_event
                           join d in dbContext.stop_details on s.stop_id equals d.id
                           where (d.ship_date >= startDate && d.ship_date <= endDate)
                           select new
                                        {
```

to add to the strangness, this runs fine:

```
  var stopEvents2 = (from s in dbContext.stop_event
                          join d in dbContext.stop_details on s.stop_id equals d.id
                          where d.ship_date >= startDate && d.ship_date <= endDate
                          select d).ToArray();
```

To check the data integrity the following runs fine in SSMS:

```
    SELECT *
  FROM FlexEDI.dbo.stop_event
  join FlexEDI.dbo.stop_details on stop_details.id = stop_event.stop_id
  where ship_date >= '7/1/2017' and ship_date <= '7/31/2017'
```

Using diagnostics tools the query with just one condition shows this (both have the same select portion):

```
 FROM    [dbo].[stop_event] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[stop_details] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[stop_id] = [Extent2].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[customers] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[customer_id] = [Extent3].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[edi_shipment_status_codes] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[exception_status_code] = [Extent4].[code]
WHERE [Extent2].[ship_date] >= @p__linq__0
```

While the query with both shows this:

```
    FROM    [dbo].[stop_event] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[stop_details] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[stop_id] = [Extent2].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[customers] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[customer_id] = [Extent3].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[edi_shipment_status_codes] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[exception_status_code] = [Extent4].[code]
WHERE ([Extent2].[ship_date] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[ship_date] <= @p__linq__1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by:
This change "breaks" it? You mean - the code is not working or is working very slowly? Do you use SQL Server as a database? Did you check what query is being sent to SQL server (using SQL server profiler) ? Did you check what is execution plan for this query?

Comment: I thought these answers were already provided, sorry:  Break it means it takes over a min. to run.  Yes SQL server.  No, I have not used a profiler yet...I will do that and post what I find.

Comment: You can use [EF logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: See updated question with results from diagnostic tools.  Using EF logging to the console shows the same results.

Comment: @JoeRuder Can you post the generated query with them wrapped in parenthesis?

Comment: Since the generated SQL query is just fine, it sounds like bad query execution plan (or parameter sniffing) issue. Creating index on `ship-date` column or forcing plan recompile might help.

Comment: I agree with Ivan Stoev - the solution is to look for execution plan - and there should be the answer (why it is taking so long) - parameter sniffing is also my guess.
Post here execution plan (image) and if you cannot find cause looking at execution plan - we may help :)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I will get the requested items and post

Comment: Hello. Could you switch to CompareTo method of DateTime and check again the response times ? The Linq Engine might have easier translation for CompareTo. Also could you turn off the Eager loading and also try the generated sql query to your server?

Comment: Yes I can, I will be back at this client tomorrow and will update this.  Thank you...